# Angular 1 component save current input values when clicking outside the input or other inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller, angularjs-components

i am using angular material and have a modal that pops up with places where you can edit data, this inline editing area is created using a components. When user click the values, these values become editable and when user hit enter key the value get saved, when user hit esc key , modal get cancelled.

sometimes when an user click a value to edit, then accidentally proceed to click out side the modal or another value field  without hitting enter, the data is not saving and user have to retype everything again. So i want a feature , when user click outside the modal while they are editing , data should get save automatically anyway or they  clicked another value to edit without hitting enter on the current value ,data should save automatically

i have my attempt commented out in below code. The problem with my attempt is , 1) it doesn't save when clicking outside the modal, 2) it doesn't save the current edited value when clicking another value, it save only when clicking inside the same input field where i am editing the value.so it essentially only replaces enter key with click but doesnt give me any of the feature i described above.

if its possible, once a user click the value and the value become editable, anywhere else  the user click should trigger the save the current entered values .
here is the component and controller code

```
component defined 
let inlineEditComponent = {
restrict:'E',
bindings:{
    identifier:"=", 
    value:"=",
    onUpdate:"=",
    display:"=",
    valueName: "="
},
controller,
template
};

////controller 

class InlineEditController{
constructor($scope, $element, $attrs,$timeout, $mdMedia){
    "ngInject";

    this.$scope   = $scope;
    this.$element = $element;
    this.$attrs   = $attrs;
    this.$timeout = $timeout;
    this.$mdMedia = $mdMedia;
}

$onInit = () => {
    this.isEditing = false;

    this._input = angular.element(document.querySelector('#inline-input-box'));

    //handle when user hits enter
    this.$element.bind("keydown keypress", (event) => {
        if (event.which === 13) {
            this.$scope.$apply(() => {
                this.save();
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    //handle when user hits esc
    this.$element.bind("keydown keypress", (event)  => {
        if (event.which === 27) {
            this.$scope.$apply(()  =>{
                this.cancel();
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        }

      //my attempt 

          //    this.$element.bind("click", (event) => {
    //         this.$scope.$apply(() => {
    //             this.save();
    //             this.isEditing = true;
    //     });
    //         event.preventDefault();

    //     }); 

    });

    enableEditMode = (ev) => {
        this.isEditing = true;

        if(this.identifier == 'property'){
            this.initDataTypeFields();
        }

        this.$timeout(() =>{
            this._input[0].focus();
        },100)
    }

    save = () => {
        this._input.blur();
        this.isEditing = false;

        if (this.isTimestamp) { 
            this.value.value = moment(this.selectedDate).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
        }

        if(this.isSelectValue){
            this.value.value = this.selectedMultiValue.id;
            this.valueNameMulti  = this.selectedMultiValue.value;
        }

        this.onUpdate(this.value, this.display);
    }
```

Comment: your code snippet is broken

Comment: meant to insert code, fixed.

Comment: need a working snippet to be able to debug your problem

Comment: If you fix it, please add your answer for others! and do not let the question without answer